# JavaScript - getElementsByName using partial wildcard

Tags: javascript, automation, element

I'm working on an automation project in which I have a web adapter with a search box but there is no search button the only way to proceed is to hit enter. I found a previous thread which provided a solution for getting the text box element by ID, however in this scenario the text box ID is randomly generated each time the page loads.

The name of the text box also always changes except the end of the name always ends with `_text`.

I have tried to use `*_text` as my parameter in the following script but I keep getting an error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong or are there any better suggestions?

```
eventname = "keydown"

elementID = "*_text"
```

---

```
function os_RaiseEvent(eventname,elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementsByName(elementId)[0];
    var event;

    if(document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent(eventname, true, false);
        if(eventname == "keydown" || eventname == "keyup") {
            event.keyCode = 13;
        }
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else if(document.createEventObject) {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        if(eventname == "keydown" || eventname == "keyup") {
            event.keyCode = 13;
        }
        element.fireEvent("on" + eventname, event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should mind to mark an answer to finish that topic.

Answer (score 4):

Run this special kind of attribute selector `[id$="_text"]` with `document.querySelectorAll()`, if you want to have a list of all elements, or `document.querySelector()`, if you want to select one particular element.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[id$="_text"]'));
```

```html
<p id="foo_text">Foo</p>
<p id="bar_text">Bar</p>
<p id="baz_text">Baz</p>
```

You can adopt this solution for any HTML attribute. If you want to query by name attribute, use `document.querySelectorAll('[name$="_text"]')`.

Comment: You are welcome, please mind to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am little bit confused about the attribute...is it `name` or `id`. Though that matters little, you can try with [`Attribute Ends With Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

You can use the selector in [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for selecting more than one elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name$="_text"]')[0]
```

**OR:** with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for selecting the first matched element:

```
document.querySelector('[name$="_text"]')
```

```js
let firstVal = document.querySelectorAll('[name$="_text"]')[0].value
console.log(firstVal);
```

```html
<input name="1_text" value="one"/>
<input name="2_text" value="two"/>
<input name="3_text" value="three"/>
```

Comment: This is wrong.  You suggest using `querySelectorAll()` and then get the first element, so you should use (or at least suggest) `querySelector()`.  That's not what's wrong though.  The actual code is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski I agree, or copy/pasta mistake, but I suggested he proof-read it and he's edited it three times now and not fixed it, so it's just wrong.  At least the OP has a correct answer.